# Can i use ">" character in url

Tags: php, html, url

I am going to use ">" character in my url? 
will this cause any problem?

> cats.php?cat=26&parent=24&position=24>26>

Comment: Doesn't have to be. Apache accepts it unencoded, but browsers escape it automatically anyway. You should however `htmlentities()` encode it at the very least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, and it probably won't cause any problems.
But to be on the safe side you should take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a URL safe character, so it should be [URL encoded](https://www.php.net/urlencode): `%3E`

Answer (score 1):

Encode it rather than including it directly:

```
cats.php?cat=26&number=26%3E24
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [RFC 3986 2. Characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2), only letters and digits from the US-ASCII character set and the symbols `%:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=-._~` are allowed in URLs.

You have to [%-encode](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) ">".

Answer (score 0):

Just escape it

```
>>> escape(">")
"%3E"
```

Comment: Is that Python? Odd choice considering the tags on the question.

Comment: hmm… and I get *NameError: name 'escape' is not defined* when I try that. Is this an "Use an unspecified language that is not the one mentioned in the question, with an unspecified library" answer?

Comment: It's just javascript. This is a "let me show how this will become encoded using the first console I find" answer.